# How can I open Static Wallpapers of Android programmatically?

Tags: android, wallpaper

How can I open Static Wallpapers of Android programmatically. There is a method to open the Live Wallpapers using

```
WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER));
```

but I could not find any solution.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First select photo:

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

And then in OnActivityResult, you can use WallpaperManager to set bitmap.

Comment: i want to open static wallpapers not gallery.